# Delete clone button not functioning

Tags: jquery

I have a function that clones a set of fields in a form and generates new names for them, part of this function is the ability to delete the clone but it doesn't want to work.

Function;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newNum = 2;
    cloneMe = function(el) {
        var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'container' + newNum);
        newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/form\[1\]/g, 'form['+newNum+']'));
        newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/id="(.*?)"/g, 'id="1'+newNum+'"'));
        $('#cloneb').before(newElem);
        $('#delete_name'+ newNum).html('<p id="rem_field"><a href="#"><span>Delete Line</span></a></p>');
        newNum++;
    };

    $('p#rem_field').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('div').remove();
    return false;
});    

});
```

and the div where the delete button would go;

```
<div id="delete_name"></div>
```

The delete button should be unique for each clone, how would I go about changing this so it actually works. jsFiddle for live example http://jsfiddle.net/ZBK2h/1/

Comment: Id of an element must be unique use class instead of ID for delete ex `<p class="rem_field"><a href="#"><span>Delete Line</span></a></p>` then `$('.rem_field').live(...)`

Comment: also since you are using jquery 1.7, use `.on()` instead of `.live()` like `$(document).on('click', '.rem_field', function(){..})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny he should use `on` but 1.7 still supports it so no issues.

Comment: I made the changed you've suggested but the div is still showing as empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few changes... use `delete_name` as a class name

```
<div class="delete_name"></div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newNum = 2;
    cloneMe = function(el) {
        var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'container' + newNum);
        $('#cloneb').before(newElem);
        newElem.find('.delete_name').html('<p class="rem_field"><a href="#"><span>Delete Line</span></a></p>');
        newNum++;
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.rem_field', function() {
        $(this).closest('.instance').remove();
        return false;
    });    

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5KXub/)

Comment: Hmm very strange, when I click 'delete line' the page seems to reload but now with a '#' at the end of the url but nothing deletes, I've even copied directly from the jsFiddle

Comment: I made a new blank page with just the code from the jsFiddle and im getting the same results, the 'Delete Line' link just reloads the page withe a '#' after the url and deletes nothing

Comment: @RathBaloth it means the click handler is not getting registered

Comment: can you inspect that delete element and see whether the class `rem_field` is present... also which is the jQuery version used?

Comment: Oh damn, sorry, I was using an old jQuery, did not notice. Thanks